# Bluetooth auto connecting to trusted device

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, bluetooth, ios

I have my iPhone 6 plus successfully connected(and also trusted) via bluetooth to my new raspberry pi 3. But I have to manually go into settings and connect each time. For the project I'm working on I wanted the pi to connect to my iPhone automatically when in range. I'm not even sure this is possible and I've looked up and tried almost everything. Any help would be greatly strong textappreciated